# Как узнать размеры padding задаваемые через setStyleSheet?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qss, qlabel

Есть `QLabel` с фиксированной шириной, с заданными стилями:

```
self.name.setStyleSheet("QLabel#name{background:#fff;border:0px;padding: 0 10px 0 10px}")
```

В другом месте мне нужно, для некоторых манипуляций, узнать размеры `padding`, который был задан через стили.  
Если ли для этого какой-то метод?

---

Да, как "разработчик" я знаю размер и могу вручную прописать там где надо, но хотелось бы не плодить магических чисел, да, можно добавить комментарий, но:
если в стилях размеры `padding` поменять и ЗАБЫТЬ поменять тоже значение в другом месте, всё начнёт криво отображаться и придётся искать то место, где прописан размер `padding` вручную, а не взят из метода.

Надеюсь такой метод существует, если да, будь добры подсказать его.

---

Тот же самый вопрос про `border` указанный с стилях.

**UPD**:
Есть метод, делает "то же самое":

```
self.name.setContentsMargins(10, 0, 10, 0)
```

но:

1. С `border` всё ещё непонятно.
2. К `Padding'у` в стилях не имеет никакого отношения, т.е. костыльно можно этим заменить `padding` в стилях
3. Работает он именно `padding` - добавляет отступы ВНУТРИ виджета не изменяя размеров, а не как `MARGIN`, который должен добавлять отступы "поверх" виджета (сужу по CSS).  Баг Qt или я не правильно понял описание метода (англ слабоват)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте покрутить SpinBoxs в моем примере:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self._border        = 0
        self._paddingTop    = 0
        self._paddingRight  = 0
        self._paddingBottom = 0
        self._paddingLeft   = 0

        self.label_1 = QLabel("Это текст")

        self.label_2 = QLabel("QLabel с фиксированной шириной, с заданными стилями",  
                               objectName='name')
        self.label_2.setFixedWidth(320)

        self.label_2.setStyleSheet(""" QLabel#name{
                            background: #fff;
                            border: %dpx solid #32414B;
                            color: blue;
                            padding: %dpx %dpx %dpx %dpx;}
            """ % (self._border,
                   self._paddingTop, self._paddingRight, self._paddingBottom, self._paddingLeft))


        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_1, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)

        self.formLayout = QFormLayout()
        for item in ("border", "paddingTop", "paddingRight", "paddingBottom", "paddingLeft"):
            spinBox = QSpinBox()
            spinBox.setMinimum(0)
            spinBox.setMaximum(50)
            spinBox.setValue(0)
            spinBox.valueChanged.connect(lambda i, p=item: self.valueChangedSpin(i, p))
            self.formLayout.addRow(QLabel(item), spinBox)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout, 3, 0)

        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)

    def valueChangedSpin(self, i, p):
        if p=="paddingTop":
            self._paddingTop = i
        elif p=="paddingRight":
            self._paddingRight = i
        elif p=="paddingBottom":
            self._paddingBottom = i
        elif p=="paddingLeft":
            self._paddingLeft = i
        elif p=="border":
            self._border = i

        self.label_2.setStyleSheet(""" QLabel#name{
                            background: #fff;
                            border: %dpx solid #32414B;
                            color: blue;
                            padding: %dpx %dpx %dpx %dpx;}
            """ % (self._border,
                   self._paddingTop, self._paddingRight, self._paddingBottom, self._paddingLeft))


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Вариант второй:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, dP, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self._border        = dP["border"]
        self._paddingTop    = dP["paddingTop"]
        self._paddingRight  = dP["paddingRight"]
        self._paddingBottom = dP["paddingBottom"]
        self._paddingLeft   = dP["paddingLeft"]

        self.label_1 = QLabel("QLabel с фиксированной шириной, с заданными стилями")

        self.label_2 = QLabel("QLabel с фиксированной шириной, с заданными стилями",  
                               objectName='name')


#        self.label_2.setFixedWidth(320)


        self.label_2.resize(320, 50)

        self.label_3 = QLabel()
        self.label_3.setText("""
        "label.width"     ={},
        "width"             ={},
        "border"            ={}, 
        "paddingTop"     ={}, 
        "paddingRight"   ={}, 
        "paddingBottom"={}, 
        "paddingLeft"     ={}
        """.format(self.label_2.width(),
                   self.label_2.width() - self._paddingRight - self._paddingLeft,
                   self._border, 
                   self._paddingTop, self._paddingRight, 
                   self._paddingBottom, self._paddingLeft ))


        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_1, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 2, 0)

        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(4, 1)

        self.formLayout = QFormLayout()
        for item in ("border", "paddingTop", "paddingRight", "paddingBottom", "paddingLeft"):
            spinBox = QSpinBox()
            spinBox.setFixedWidth(80)
            spinBox.setMinimum(0)
            spinBox.setMaximum(50)
            spinBox.setValue(0)
            spinBox.valueChanged.connect(lambda i, p=item: self.valueChangedSpin(i, p))
            self.formLayout.addRow(QLabel(item), spinBox)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout, 3, 0) #, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)

    def valueChangedSpin(self, i, p):
        if p=="paddingTop":
            self._paddingTop = i
        elif p=="paddingRight":
            self._paddingRight = i
        elif p=="paddingBottom":
            self._paddingBottom = i
        elif p=="paddingLeft":
            self._paddingLeft = i
        elif p=="border":
            self._border = i

        print(self.label_1.width(), 
              self.label_2.width(),
              self.label_2.width() - self._paddingRight - self._paddingLeft)

        self.label_2.setStyleSheet(""" QLabel#name{
                            background: #fff;
                            border: %dpx solid #32414B;
                            color: blue;
                            padding: %dpx %dpx %dpx %dpx;}
            """ % (self._border,
                   self._paddingTop, self._paddingRight, self._paddingBottom, self._paddingLeft))


        self.label_3.setText("""
        "label.width"     ={},
        "width"             ={},
        "border"            ={}, 
        "paddingTop"     ={}, 
        "paddingRight"   ={}, 
        "paddingBottom"={}, 
        "paddingLeft"     ={}
        """.format(self.label_2.width(),
                   self.label_2.width() - self._paddingRight - self._paddingLeft,
                   self._border, 
                   self._paddingTop, self._paddingRight, 
                   self._paddingBottom, self._paddingLeft ))

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------


dP = {"border": 0, "paddingTop": 0, "paddingRight": 0,       # dP - dictPadding
                            "paddingBottom": 0, "paddingLeft": 0}
CSS = """ 
QLabel#name{
    background: #fff;
    border: %dpx solid #32414B;
    color: blue;
    padding: %dpx %dpx %dpx %dpx;
    }
""" % (dP["border"],
                   dP["paddingTop"], dP["paddingRight"], dP["paddingBottom"], dP["paddingLeft"])       

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    app.setStyleSheet(CSS)
    widget = MyWidget(dP)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы не совсем меня поняли.  Мне нужно другое.  У меня есть метод, который обрезает длинный текст (не помещающийся в QLabel), для этого нужно знать "рабочую" ширину QLabel `width = label.width() - padding_width * 2` (2 - потому что слева и справа padding), и вот мой вопрос в том, как узнать этот самый `padding_width` который "когда то давно" был задан стилями для `label`?

Comment: Мне не нужно повторно изменять стили QLabel.

Comment: Я вам не предлагаю повторно изменять стили QLabel. 
Я вам показал вариант того, что можно управлять размерами через значения переменных.
А именно: `padding_width = 10` . . . 
`self.name.setStyleSheet("QLabel#name{background:#fff;border:0px;padding: 0 %dpx 0 %dpx}" % (padding_width, padding_width))`
. . . 
Вот ваша ширина: 
`width = label.width() - padding_width * 2`

Comment: Это то я знаю, спасибо, забыл в вопросе написать про этот вариант: я хочу все стили вынести в отдельный файл QSS и подключить к программе (не знаю как правильней выразиться), и в таком случает трюк с переменной уже не прокатит, увы.  Насколько я понял, всё таки вытащить значения свойств стилей нельзя?  Увы, похоже придётся делать исключение и для этой части программы стили прописывать на месте, а не в отдельном файле.

Comment: Все стили вынести в отдельный файл QSS - это правильно. С переменными тоже все в порядке. Смотрите второй вариант ответа. Понаблядайте что происходит. Поэкспериментируйте.

Comment: Ну это получается нужно иметь какую-то глобальную перменную, чтобы из неё брать значения, что не есть хорошо, потому передавать через параметры объектов - плохая идея, потому что у меня получается слишком длинная иерархия от `Main_window` до виджета в котором это нужно, и вмешиваться в родительские виджеты не лучший вариант - тогда уж глобальная переменная звучит даже лучше.  Но учитывая что файл QSS имеет множество стилей, и не только для одного виджета может понадобиться то, что в вопросе, то контролировать всё это дело очень рискованно.

Comment: [Продолжение]  Т.ч. пока что лучшим вариантом остаётся сделать исключение и задавать стили для конкретно этого виджета на месте, используя локальную переменную в самом виджете.  Ещё идею с глобальной переменой и мониторингом можно развить написанием модуля (или взятием готового) наподобии SASS, чтобы он значения менял поимённо, например в QCC пишем `padding: %widget_id-padding_size%px`, а модуль заменят `%widget_id-padding_size%` на значение переменной `QSS["widget_id"]["padding_size"]`, и в нужном месте мы можем взять значение этой переменной, но неуверен, оправдано ли это.

Comment: Под `widget_id` у нас может быть обычный `QLabel#name` для которого и происходит замена.